# Merge Jquery .css with CSS transition

Tags: jquery, css

```
#contact{position:absolute;right:20px;top:15%;width:450px;opacity:0.8;color:#fff;background-color:rgba(0,0,0,0.5);overflow:hidden;border-radius:212px;height:425px;width:425;display:none;-webkit-transform:scale(10);-webkit-transition:1s all ease-in-out;}
.contact-small{display:block;-webkit-transform:scale(1);}
```

I have this along with  a jquery script:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$("#contactopt").click(function(){
    $("#contact").addClass('contact-small');
);
});
```

And HTML:

```
<!-- NAVIGATION -->
<table id="nav"><tr><td style="vertical-align:middle;text-align:center;font-size:0.25em;">
<span id="homeopt">home</span><br>
<span id="contactopt">contact</span><br>
<span id="projectsopt">projects</span>
</td></tr></table>
<!-- /NAVIGATION -->

<TABLE id="contact"><tr><td style="vertical-align:middle;text-align:center;">!</td></tr></table>
```

*I used Chrome for the testing*

But.. when the change happens, I see no animation. Can anyone give me a solution for this?
Thanks in advance. :) Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: There is also a double 'display' declaration in css.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try to play with classes instead of adding css directly to the object. I.E. you can have

```
$("#mercuryopt").click(function(){
    $("#mercuryon").addClass('mercuryion-small');
);
```

and in your css

```
.mercuryon-small {
  -webkit-transform: scale(1) !important; //if you are using an id, then !important is needed
}
```

See fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/guybrushthreepwood/597sD/

Comment: I fixed the code, and added the HTML code. Can you please modify your answer according to it, please?

Comment: I tried the code (after modification) but it wasn't working. So it would be better if you do that. :) Thanks in advance.

Comment: The opt div isn't containing mercury (or contact here).

Comment: Harshal Gajjar : The code you provided is completely changed from the first version of your question. This fiddle seems to work http://jsfiddle.net/guybrushthreepwood/597sD/7/